# lists inside a list

Tags: prolog

i am writing a predicate in prolog to delete an atom in a list, but i stuck on how to check if the atom is whether a list inside a list. any suggestions.

Comment: Please specify more exactly what you want to do. Delete the first occurrence? Delete all occurrences?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate throughout a list and get type of each element and compare if it is atom's type, if not return desired bool.